# Modified Sum of Products

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, products, integers

A given number **k** is to be expressed as a sum of products of integers keeping in mind that the integers used in above process do not exceed their cumulative sum as **100**.

For e.g.,

**k = 19** can be expressed as **15 + 4** or **3*5 + 2*2**, so the cumulative sum is **3 + 5 + 2 + 2 = 12**

A simple approach is to prime factorize the given integer but the problem arises when the sum of prime factors exceed 100 and in expressing primes as in required form.

**k can be large upto 100000**.

Comment: What exactly is your question? (What do you want to know?)

Comment: I want to express the given number as the sum of products as stated in example i.e., 19 = 3*5 + 2*2, there can be many expressions i just want any of them.

Comment: If you want an explicit formula in terms of $k$, I don't think that is possible ... if you want a method / algorithm to find such a representation, that may be possible

Comment: No I don't want any explicit formula, just any method or algorithm as it is always possible to express the number as required.

Comment: I put together some examples and a general method ... does that help?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use the [base 3 (or ternary) representation of $k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system).

---

For example, if the number is $k=500$, then you could notice that $3^5 = 243$, so $$500 = 3 \cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 2 + 7\cdot 2$$

Or if $k=1000$, I would use $$1000 = 3^6 + 3^5 + 3^3 + 1 = 729 + 243 + 27 + 1$$

Comment: As $k$ grows to **100000** the sum of the numbers used in sum of products representation exceeds 100, for e.g., k = 9841(111111111 in base 3), cumulative sum = 3*8 + 3*7 + 3*6 + 3*5 + 3*4 + 3*3 + 3*2 + 3*1 + 1 = 109>100

Comment: How do you know it's possible to do it within 100?

Comment: It's stated that it is possible.

Comment: Stated where? Just curious